# How to use Mixpanel in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, mixpanel

How one can include [Mixpanel analytics](https://mixpanel.com/) in [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)?

Honestly, I'm new to Nuxt.js and Vue, and Mixpanel but website I inherited is descant so I'd rather learn than change. Adding Google Analytic is pretty straight forward as there's a great package [nuxtjs google-analytics](https://google-analytics.nuxtjs.org/); it only requires adding `googleAnalytics` to Nuxt config and all is done magically.

For Mixpanel I have found both [vue-mixpanel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mixpanel) and [mixpanel-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mixpanel-browser) but I'm not really sure how to use them. The first one seems appropriate but once I initiate the plugin I'm confused where to use the `this.$mixpanel` references. Is there some "on page load" event? No idea how to add something to page's header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Nuxt` you have layouts. Each page is going to be utilizing a layout. You can add a `watcher` to the `$route` object, and determine when it changes and track the page views in this way fairly easily.

```
// layouts/default.vue (or whatever layout is being used)

watch: {
  $route: {
    handler: function () {
      // from the vue-mixpanel documentation
      this.$mixpanel.track('event name', {
        distinct_id: 'unique client id',
      })
    },
    immediate: true // fires this function immediately when the object has bound to the watcher

  }
}
```

Mind you that if different pages use different layouts, they'll need to all implement this same logic, which you could abstract into a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Comment: Cool, that seems to do the trick. Seems like there's going to be a bit manual work on checking for privacy and passing distinct events, but just checked that `this.$route` has most of what I want.